# How to change button background button in another activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, button

hi i have 3 XML layout with Button (without class or activity or fragment) and use in view pager in another activity ... now i want change button background in view pager activity when my condition is true. how to do it ?

this image :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sssc1.png)

Comment: `i want change button background in view pager activity when my condition is true` - do it inside an `if` statement? I suggest you add more detail and possibly some pseudo code for better, more accurate comments and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the background of a button, first you must have the button initialized. Lets say you initialize the button as such:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.theButton);
```

Of course, the ID of your button is whatever you set it as in the XML file. You can change the background color whenever you want in the same scope as your declaration of the button as such:

```
myButton.setBackgroundColor(R.color.anyColor);
```

Hopefully this answers your question as it's quite confusing.